# Is a regular system of parameters always algebraically independent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be a regular local ring containing a field $k$, let $\mathfrak{m}$ be the maximal ideal of $A$, let $x_{1},\dotsc,x_{n} \in \mathfrak{m}$ be a regular system of paramaters for $A$. Is the set $\{x_{1},\dotsc,x_{n}\}$ algebraically independent over $k$?

Thoughts:

1. The condition "containing a field $k$" is there because the answer is "no" for regular local rings "arising from arithmetic", for example if we take $A = \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ then $p$ is not algebraically independent over the image of $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$.
2. Suppose $A$ is the local ring of a smooth $k$-algebra where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. There is a faithfully flat (hence injective) ring homomorphism $k[t_{1},\dotsc,t_{n}]_{(t_{1},\dotsc,t_{n})} \to A$ where $(t_{1},\dotsc,t_{n})A = \mathfrak{m}$. So there exist polynomials $f_{1},\dotsc,f_{n} \in (t_{1},\dotsc,t_{n})$ mapping to $x_{1},\dotsc,x_{n}$ (after possibly multiplying each $x_{i}$ by a unit of $A$). Now it would suffice to show that $f_{1},\dotsc,f_{n}$ are algebraically independent. If $n = 1$ (i.e. $A$ is DVR), then the answer is "yes" as follows: if $f := a_{0} + a_{1}x_{1} + \dotsb + a_{s}x_{1}^{s} = 0$ with $a_{i} \in k$, then $a_{0} = 0$ (otherwise $f$ is a unit of $A$); then divide by $x_{1}$ and proceed by decreasing induction.

Comment: I one looks at the associated graded ring of $A$ with respect to $m$ (which is isomorphic to a polynomial ring in $n$ variables over $A/m$) can conclude that $\hat x_1,\dots,\hat x_n\in m/m^2$ are algebraically independent over $A/m$. If $f\in k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ satisfies $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0$ then $f(\hat x_1,\dots,\hat x_n)=0$ and therefore the coefficients of $f$ belongs to $m$. But the nonzero elements of $k$ are invertible in $A$, and thus $f=0$.

Comment: @user26857 Great, thanks.